# hide youtube-dl's window with executable

Tags: python, youtube-dl

My simplified code in python 3.5 is:

```
...    
command = 'youtube-dl -f bestaudio MYURL &'
outfile = open('test.txt','w')
call(command.split(), stdout=outfile, stderr=outfile)
...
```

I run it from a tkinter GUI. It works fine from Sublime Text, but when I make my script executable (via cx_freeze), youtube-dl shows an empty black window for a few seconds.

It keeps going perfectly but the window is annoying. Is there a way to hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stdout does not work in a GUI application, you need to set the correct flags through the win32api to hide the windows of the subprocess. The use of `call()` will not work as it does not support the [STARTUPINFO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO) helper, instead you can use `Popen()`

Something like this should do the trick:

```
from subprocess import Popen, STARTUPINFO, STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW, SW_HIDE, PIPE

si = STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE

proc = Popen(['youtube-dl', '-f', 'bestaudio', MYURL], stdin=PIPE, 
                                                       stdout=stdout_file, 
                                                       stderr=PIPE, 
                                                       shell=False, 
                                                       startupinfo=si)
ret_code = process.wait()
stdout_file.flush()
```

Comment: Wow it works! I was litterally getting crazy with this issue!! I couldn't find the solution anywhere! Thank you very much!